# How to know the filetype through python

Tags: python

In the very beginning,I tried to do like this(hoped to get some useful information in the head):

```
>>content=open("fileurl","rb").read()
```

I found that PNG (png)'s Header  is lik this: 89504E47 (I don't know wheather it's true or not)
But when I did in this way,the result is:

```
>>> content[:20]
'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x01\x90'
```

the `\x`is what?
Hope someone can help!Thanks very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`'\x89'` is a representation of non-printable byte with value `0x89` (that's `137`).

As for finding file types in Python, there is already [**`mimetypes`**](http://docs.python.org/library/mimetypes.html) module for that.

```
import mimetypes
type, subtype = mimetypes.guess_type(filename_or_url)
```

In action:

```
>>> mimetypes.guess_type('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9a/PNG_transparency_demonstration_2.png')
('image/png', None)
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're seeing is an escaped byte in a Python string. `\x89` means a single byte with value 89 (hex) or 137 (decimal).

```
>>> ord('\x89')
137
>>> 0x89
137
>>> chr(137)
'\x89'
```

Answer (score 0):

The `\x89` means the value is not a printable ASCII character.

The `\r` and `\n` are also ASCII characters without an "obvious" graphic symbol.

Read this: http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals